# tkinter create undetermined number of checkboxes/IntVar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

For a project I am working on, I am loading some csv datafile into a dataframe using read_csv. I then print the dataframe on a tkinter frame using some Entry widgets. The user can populate or edit some entries. I would like to create at the beginning of each row a checkbox so that once the user is happy with the edits I upload the "dataframe" for which checkboxes are checked into a database.

When loading the content of the dataframe I can create the desired checkboxes but unfortunately the number of rows of the input datafile is not fixed. For each checkbox I would like to have a unique variable and hence I would like to create an undetermined number of IntVar variables.

within my Tk-inherited class I have the fileLoad function

```
def fileLoad(self):
    df = pd.read_csv(self.filename)
    rows, cols = df.shape
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            e = Entry(self.ViewFrame)
            e.insert(0, df.iloc[r, c])
            e.grid(row=r, column=c + 1)
```

so how can I create a variable number of checkboxes positioned in column=0 please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find a way as follow:

```
def fileLoad(self):
    df = pd.read_csv(self.filename)
    rows, cols = df.shape
    vars = []
    for r in range(rows):
        var = IntVar()
        vars.append(var)
        ckbox = ttk.Checkbutton(self.ViewFrame, variable=var)
        ckbox.grid(row=r+10, column=0)
        for c in range(cols):
            e = Entry(self.ViewFrame)
            e.insert(0, df.iloc[r, c])
            e.grid(row=r + 10, column=c + 1)
```

I store the variables var into a list called vars.